# How to hide a sub report if no data - Telerik Report

Tags: c#, telerik, telerik-reporting

Telerik prints blank fields if the data source is null. how to hide the sub report if there is no data?

[image]

Comment: You could likely set a binding on the sub report to hide it if row count = 0